# Importing Numpy into Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, numpy, sublimetext3

I'm new to coding and I have been learning it on Jupyter. I have anaconda, Sublime Text 3, and the numpy package installed on my Mac.

On Jupyter, we would import numpy by simply typing
    `import numpy as np`

However, this doesnt seem to work on Sublime as I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to get this working. Thanks!

Comment: I think this problem can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54859597/sublime-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named

Answer (score 1):

If you have Annaconda, install Spyder.

If you continue to have this problem, you could check all the lib install from anaconda.
I suggest you to install nmpy from anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([19,28,48])
```