# Sublime ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sublimetext3

In Sublime having having issues running simple imports like `import numpy` or `import pandas`. I am able to do this in my windows command prompt.

When I run the code below in both sublime and `cmd` prompt:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I receive:

```
C:\Users\MICHAEL\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\python.exe
```

When I run the below code i can see the same file paths:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

**Sublime**

```
'C:\\Udemy\\WebScraping','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\python37.zip','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\DLLs',C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\lib','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\lib\\site-packages'
```

**CMD**

```
'','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\python37.zip','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\DLLs',C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\lib','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6','C:\\Users\\MICHAEL\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6\\lib\\site-packages'
```

Comment: Having issues? What type of issues? Please post any error messages including full traceback.

Comment: How did you install those numpy and pandas?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: @gameon67, in the windows command prompt "pip install numpy" I receive "Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\michael\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.15.4)". In python cmd prompt terminal if i type "import numpy" it goes to the next line with no errors

Comment: Solution was to remove all instances referencing anaconda from Environment Variables - User Variables & Environment Variables - System Variables, reinstall both Anaconda, check box for adding path to Environment Variables and then reinstall Sublime